# Why the Constructor for Sklearn Transformer within ColumnTransformer is invoked twice, further, the parameters for two invocations are different

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

**Three questions** for below code and its output:

1. Why the constructor for MyDebug Transformer being invoked twice, first time for line 26, and second time for line 37?
2. Why the two invocations show different parameter *myname*, especially weird for second invocation for line 37, why it doesn't take in the passed parameter, not even default value, but None instead as in the output?
3. If you uncomment line 36, ct1.fit, it also invokes Transformer's transform function, which is only expected for ct1.fit_transform?

**Environment**: Python version is 3.6.10 and Sklearn version is 0.22.1

```
  1 import numpy as np
  2 from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
  3 from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
  4 from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin
  5 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
  6 from datetime import datetime
  7
  8
  9
 10 class MyDebug(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
 11     def __init__(self, myname="HELP"):
 12         print(f"intialized with myname: {myname}")
 13         self._name = myname
 14         print (f"Debug.__init__ being invoked for {myname}, {self._name}, {id(self)}")
 15     def transform(self, X):
 16         print (f"in {self._name} transform with type: {type(X)}, shape: {X.shape} at {datetime.now()}")
 17         self.shape = X.shape
 18         # what other output you want
 19         return X
 20     def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
 21         print (f"in {self._name} fit with type: {type(X)}, shape: {X.shape} at {datetime.now()}")
 22         return self
 23
 24
 25 print("************************************************************")
 26 ct1 = ColumnTransformer(
 27     [("norm1", Pipeline(steps=[("norm", Normalizer(norm='l1')), ("debug", MyDebug("MYDEBUG_1"))]), [0, 1]),
 28      ("norm2", Pipeline(steps=[("norm", Normalizer(norm='l1')), ("debug", MyDebug("MYDEBUG_2"))]), slice(2, 10))])
 29
 30 print("************************************************************")
 31 print(f"id(ct1): {id(ct1)}")
 32 X = np.array([[0., 1., 2., 2., 0., 1., 2., 2.],
 33               [1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.]])
 34
 35 print("************************************************************")
 36 # ret = ct1.fit(X)
 37 ret = ct1.fit_transform(X)
 38 print("************************************************************")
 39 print(f"id(ct1): {id(ct1)}")
 40 print(f"type(ret): {type(ret)}")
 41 print(type(ct1.named_transformers_["norm1"]), id(ct1.named_transformers_["norm1"]), id(ct1.named_transformers_["norm2"]), "\n",
 42 type(ct1.named_transformers_["norm1"].named_steps["norm"]), id(ct1.named_transformers_["norm1"].named_steps["norm"]), id(ct1.named_transformers_["norm2"].named_steps["norm"]), "\n",
 43 type(ct1.named_transformers_["norm1"].named_steps["debug"]), id(ct1.named_transformers_["norm1"].named_steps["debug"]), id(ct1.named_transformers_["norm2"].named_steps["debug"]))
```

**Output:**

```
************************************************************
intialized with myname: MYDEBUG_1
Debug.__init__ being invoked for **MYDEBUG_1, MYDEBUG_1**, 140118618819160
intialized with myname: MYDEBUG_2
Debug.__init__ being invoked for **MYDEBUG_2, MYDEBUG_2**, 140118618819216
************************************************************
id(ct1): 140118618819328
************************************************************
intialized with myname: None
Debug.__init__ being invoked for **None, None**, 140118618819944
in None fit with type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape: (2, 2) at 2021-03-24 00:45:41.850603
in None transform with type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape: (2, 2) at 2021-03-24 00:45:41.851159
intialized with myname: None
Debug.__init__ being invoked for **None, None**, 140118618820392
in None fit with type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape: (2, 6) at 2021-03-24 00:45:41.852955
in None transform with type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape: (2, 6) at 2021-03-24 00:45:41.852995
************************************************************
id(ct1): 140118618819328
type(ret): <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'> 140118618819776 140118618820000 
 <class 'sklearn.preprocessing._data.Normalizer'> 140118618819888 140118618820112 
 <class '__main__.MyDebug'> 140118618819944 140118618820392
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why the constructor for MyDebug Transformer being invoked twice, first time for line 26, and second time for line 37?

The instantiation at line 26 should be expected, because you call the class.  It happens again at line 37 because `ColumnTransformer` [clones its transformers](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py#L437) before fitting.

> 2. Why the two invocations show different parameter myname, especially weird for second invocation for line 37, why it doesn't take in the passed parameter, not even default value, but None instead as in the output?

This is in part because your custom estimator doesn't adhere to [the sklearn API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#parameters-and-init): `__init__` parameters need to match exactly the attribute names being set.  This is because of how sklearn clones estimators: the parameters are grabbed using `get_params`, and then a new class is instantiated using those parameters.  The 0.21 behavior of `get_params`, in the case of mismatched parameters/attributes, is to return `None`; in 0.24 that changes to raising an `AttributeError`.

> 3. If you uncomment line 36, ct1.fit, it also invokes Transformer's transform function, which is only expected for ct1.fit_transform?

In order to properly decide whether its output will be sparse or dense, `ColumnTransformer.fit` actually calls `ColumnTransformer.fit_transform` (rather than the usual reverse) ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py#L469)).

Comment: Thank you Ben so much for your great detailed answers, I don't understand why it need cloning the estimators and didn't find the clone from the given Source, can you ping point to the line if possible? Actually, the most request to you, as your answer here is so great, I intentionally posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784411/five-questions-associated-with-pandas-dataframe-groupby) before responding back to you here, as I believe you can help me on that one as well. Highly appreciated !

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head why/whether the transformers _need_ to be cloned, but I've added a source link for where that happens.

Comment: Thank you again Ben. FYI: such clone is really good for my purpose, which actually drove me digging and raising the question, as I create a transformer instance, and then pass it several places with different number of columns,  I am wondering how it works if it is the same instance... If possible, please help me groupby question, which I raised ~1 year ago against a blog, but I didn't get the answer and thus stuck in my mind, with your crispy answer here, I bet you surely have deep understanding on these APIs.  Thanks again !